# Undefined index when user returns in same session

Tags: php, switch-statement, isset

I have a simple login system with sessions. The user is being redirected to a page when the user succesfully logs in.

The problem is when the user leaves my site and comes back later to index.php (the same session) the user will get "Undefined index" because there's no parameter supplied when the user enter my site and is still logged in.

I use php switch to control my pages.

I have this code first in my index.php:

```
require_once('function.php');
session_start();

if (!is_user()) {
redirect('signin.php');
} 
?>
```

My file with switch looks like this:

```
<?php




$p=$_REQUEST['p'];          
if (isset($p)) { 
    switch ($p) {

   case "vine":
                include "vine.php";

            break;


}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously *$_REQUEST['p']* is undefined.

If you want your script to still know the **p** parameter when a user returns, you must somehow save it for further requests. This could be done like this in **index.php**:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $p = isset($_REQUEST['p']) ? 
        $_REQUEST['p'] : (
            isset($_SESSION['p']) ? 
                $_SESSION['p'] : 
                false
        )
    );
    if ($p !== false) {
        $_SESSION['p'] = $p;
        switch ($p) {
            case "vine": include "vine.php";
            break;
        }
    } else {
        die ('Unknown category ....');
    }
?>
```

The code looks for an **explicitely given parameter** *p* and takes this if available. Otherwise it looks for a **session parameter** *p*.

Else it sets *p* to false to indicate that no value is avaible.

If a value for *p* is given, the session variable *$_SESSION['p']* is set. And, of course, *sesssion_start()* must be called at the top of the script to make session variables available.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I got it working inspired by your help :)

I have my switch-statements in article.php.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the 'Invalid index' comes from `$p=$_REQUEST['p'];`. You want to check whether that array element exists.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['p'])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['p']))
{
    $p = $_REQUEST['p'];          
    // ...
}
```

But notice this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php#example-5520